# Traefik don't keep real ip

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, syslog-ng, traefik

I have a problem with Traefik, I want to log from a server with syslog-ng (docker). I have logs but I have reverse_proxy name and I want source IP not the name of traefik. I wish to keep source IP from the host. traefik.yml :

```
global:
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    watch: true
    useBindPortIP: true
    exposedByDefault: false

  file:
    filename: /etc/traefik/config.yml
    watch: true

log:
  level: INFO
  format: common

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https

  https:
    address: ":443"

  udp:
    address: ":514/udp"

  tcp:
    address: ":514"

udp:
  services:
    syslog-ng:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: ":514/udp"
tcp:
  services:
    syslog-ng:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: ":514"
        forwardedHeaders: true

certificatesResolvers:
  le:
    acme:
      email: responsable.informatique@exemple.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        # used during the challenge
        entryPoint: http
```

syslog-ng.conf:

```
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
#*.* @ly****-app0037.******.com

*.* @@1**.***.***.***

#*.* action(type=omfwd" target="1**.***.***.***" port="601" protocol="tcp"
#               action.resumeRetryCount ="100"
#               queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
#*.* @@remote-host:514
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

It's like NAT reverse but I don't know here I can find the configuration in traefik.

Thank for read me
Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't understand you wrong, you just need to add a line in your YML file:

target: 514
published: 1514
protocol: udp
**mode: host** <-----

regards

Comment: Hello thanks for answer ! So I tried to do that but nothing.

Regards